# Jena (on Ubuntu) gives NoClassDefFoundError for ModelFactory

Tags: java, ubuntu, jena, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run (an external project) code that uses Jena.

Here is what I did:

1. downloaded apache-jena-3.8.0.tar.gz and unzipped it to Documents under the name apache-jena-3.8.0.
2. (not sure if relevant but...) added the jars to intellij and built and that was fine
3. went to terminal and did:

   export JENA_HOME=/[...]/Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0 (edit: this incorrectly had a /bin attached to it but I removed it after it was pointed out to me in the comments)

   export PATH=$PATH:$JENA_HOME/bin
4. run the code: it runs a little and produces some output and then gives the error:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory
       at org.imis.generator.EvoGenerator._generate(EvoGenerator.java:1010)
       at org.imis.generator.EvoGenerator.start(EvoGenerator.java:862)
       at org.imis.generator.EvoGenerator.main(EvoGenerator.java:680)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      ... 3 more
   ```

More details: I'm trying to run the code in https://github.com/mmeimaris/EvoGen. Using VMWare running Ubuntu 18.04 ... I made the mistake of editing the path variable in /etc/environment and restarted but that caused the user profile to crash and put me in a login loop, but that's fixed now.

Thank you

Comment: So your path now has `/[...]/Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0/bin/bin` on it? eg you doubled the 'bin' in the path?

Comment: sorry, no, i added the bin to the jena_home in the post only - my actual jena home is export JENA_HOME=/[...]/Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0/

Comment: The environment variables are for the command line tools; they don't set the classpath. Make sure `.../apache-jena-3.8.0/lib*` is on the classpath or, better, use a tool like maven to manage dependencies.

Comment: @AndyS I did: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:"/home/...Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0/lib" and  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:"/home/...Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0/lib*" and even added $JAVA_HOME$ to the classpath and it still gives me the same error. I tried running it from the intellij terminal and it also gave me the same error ....

Comment: It would be "`lib/*`" - and the star must be passed by java, it is not a shall expansion. JAVA_HOME sets the location of the Java runtime. In IntelliJ, presumably you are using maven or other builder (this is the best way)? See https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html  Forcommand line, you have to set "-cp" somehow.

Comment: @AndyS ... -cp "/home/izn1g08/Documents/apache-jena-3.8.0/lib/*:." worked, thanks a lot :)